# How to offset the start in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach

I want my `foreach` starts of ex : `$Element` = **10** up to **20**

At the moment :

```
foreach($lang['tech'] as $Element => $ElementName)
    {
       $parse['tt_name'] = $ElementName; // Displays the name

       if($Element > 99) // At over 99 foreach stop
       {
           break;  
       }
    }
```

I wish I had this principle in :

```
foreach($lang['tech'] as **$Element(10 to 20)** => $ElementName) // Display Element 10 to 20
    {
       $parse['tt_name'] = $ElementName; // Displays the name
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: why you are not using simple `for` loop instead of `foreach`?

Comment: `for ($i = 10; $i <= 20; $i++) { $parse['tt_name'] = $lang['tech'][$i]; }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `continue`:

```
foreach($lang['tech' as $Element => $ElementName)
{
   if($Element < 10) // Less than 10 - skip!
   {
       continue;  
   }

   $parse['tt_name'] = $ElementName; // Displays the name

   if($Element > 99) // At over 99 foreach stop
   {
       break;  
   }
}
```

Or you could use `for` loop:

```
for ($Element=10; $Element<=99; $Element++) {
    $ElementName = $lang['tech'][$Element];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If i understand you correct you want to loop only element 10 to 20, you could use a `for` loop

```
for($i = 10; $i <= 20;$i++) {
    $entry = $lang['tech'][$i];
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed ] in your foreach loop

```
foreach($lang['tech'] as $Element => $ElementName)
                    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `]` in two places in your example code:

```
foreach($lang['tech'] as $Element => $ElementName)
                    ^
```

and

```
foreach($lang['tech'] as **$Element(10 to 20)** => $ElementName)
                    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it before iterating:

```
$tech = array_filter($lang['tech'], function($key) {
    return $key >= 10 && $key <= 20;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

foreach ($tech as $key => $name) {
    // do what you need
}
```

Comment: Probably because of the PHP version :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for($Element=10; $Element <=20; $Element++)
       {
       $parse['tt_name'] = $lang['tech'][$Element]; // Displays the name
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop into the [subarray](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-slice.php) :

```
foreach( array_slice ($yourarray , 10, 10) as $Element) {
...
}
```